# Waiting for all $http.get to finish

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, deferred

I am a bit confused about this. I have two get calls inside a function. Once this complete function, that is the two get calls are done, only then is this function done with its work. how should I used $q to get this to work as I want it? This is what I have now:

```
function updateBlackList() {
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/blacklist/entries/vehicle").then(function (res){
      console.log(res)    
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      });


    })
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/blacklist/entries/person").then(function (res){
      console.log(res)     
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      });


    });
    return $q.when();

  }
```

Here withint another function I need to wait for the above fiunction to complete:

```
BlackListService.updateBlackList().then(function() {
              addVersion(server_version).then(function () {
                console.log("Blacklist update complete")
              })
            })
```

Its not doing it like I was suspecting it to do. The Blacklist complete console is called before the tw get request are done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to combine both promises in one with [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

```
function updateBlackList() {
  return $q.all([
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/blacklist/entries/vehicle")
    .then(function (res){console.log(res)})
    .catch(function (err) {console.log(err)}),

    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/blacklist/entries/person")
    .then(function (res){console.log(res)})
    .catch(function (err) {console.log(err)});
  ]);
}
```

Also, for your second example, you can chain promises to have a better looking code:

```
BlackListService.updateBlackList()
.then(function() {
  return addVersion(server_version);
})
.then(function () {
  console.log("Blacklist update complete");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$q.all`.

```
var VEHICLE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/blacklist/entries/vehicle";
var PERSON_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/blacklist/entries/person";

function updateBlackList() {
  var p1 = $http.get(VEHICLE_URL).then(whatever);
  var p2 = $http.get(PERSON_URL).then(whatever);

  return $q.all([p1, p2]);
}

updateBlackList()
  .then(whateverElse);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `$q.all([p1, p2])` ?

Comment: Ok, I guess both answers are the same, I like the variables beter